# how to control Youtube video through IBAction

Tags: ios

I am playing video in my app and I want to control video like full screen and play functions by my own IBAction is it possible?

my code is

```
- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame {
   NSString *embedHTML = @"\<html><head>\<style type=\"text/css\">\
   body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
     </style>\</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
     <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
     width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
     </body></html>";
     NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
     webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
     [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
     [self.view addSubview:webView];
     [self.view bringSubviewToFront:tvImg];
     [self.view bringSubviewToFront:btnBack];
     [self.view bringSubviewToFront:btnPlay];
     [self.view bringSubviewToFront:btnVol];
     [self.view bringSubviewToFront:btnFullScreen];
     [self.view bringSubviewToFront:btnFav];

}
```

and i am calling it in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using it in a UIWebView you can try to send a javascript Command to the UIWebView(but i'm not sure which to use or if youtube does even support it)
Unless you are loading the Video in another way there is no other option

Send this is to The UIWebView when clicking The Button:

```
var myPlayer = document.getElementById('playerid');
myPlayer.stopVideo();
```